# Android EffectFactory Bitmaps

Tags: java, android, xml, image, kotlin

I am try to use EffectFactory in Android for some Image Manipulation.
I tried out the sample and it works.
Here the Sample: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/HelloEffects/src/com/example/android/mediafx/HelloEffects.java

But how can I load an image from my smartphone?

The thing is that I don't have an ImageView here but a GLSurfaceView.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.puppy);
```

which method do I have to use to get a custom bitmap?

Comment: Not 100% sure if I understand your question but you might want to use BitmapFactory.decodeStream

Comment: and which paramter? do you have an example?

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeStream(File("/path/to/your_file.png").inputStream())

Comment: i will try it later thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this `BitmapRenderer` class to draw Bitmap in OpenGL

```
private static class BitmapRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private int[] textures;

    private Resources resources;

    public BitmapRenderer(Resources resources) {
        this.resources = resources;
    }

    private static final float[] VERTEX_COORDINATES = new float[] {
            -1.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f,
            +1.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            +1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    private static final float[] TEXTURE_COORDINATES = new float[] {
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f
    };

    private static final Buffer TEXCOORD_BUFFER = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(TEXTURE_COORDINATES.length * 4)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer().put(TEXTURE_COORDINATES).rewind();
    private static final Buffer VERTEX_BUFFER = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(VERTEX_COORDINATES.length * 4)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer().put(VERTEX_COORDINATES).rewind();

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        textures = new int[1];
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher), 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, VERTEX_BUFFER);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, TEXCOORD_BUFFER);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    }
}
```

Set your Bitmap as below:

```
glSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(1);
glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new BitmapRenderer(getResources()));
glSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
```